# How to add a delay to an Observable.interval()?

Tags: rxjs, observable, delay, intervals

Right now I'm using a `setTimeout()` which I don't really care for. Is there a native operator ? I tried [`delay`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/delay.html) but doesn't work?

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
export class CarouselListComponent implements OnInit {
  public active = 0;
  @Input() public delay = 0;
  @Input() public interval = 5500;

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(()=> {
      Observable.interval(this.interval).subscribe(()=> {
        ++this.active;
      });
    }, this.delay);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want an initial delay, you can use a [`timer`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-timer) - which can be passed an initial delay and a period:

```
Observable.timer(this.delay, this.interval).subscribe(() => {
  ++this.active;
});
```